# unable to communicate between 3 fragment,and it's result in classcastexception Error in log cat

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my MainActivity:

```
package com.davemcelf.fiction;

import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener, communicator,     sendtocontext {
ActionBar actionbar;
ViewPager viewPager;
Pager pager;
public int position;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   pager=new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pager);
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs=(PagerSlidingTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);

}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void sendcontext(int pos1) {
    Log.e("the pager position is", ""+position);
    Log.e("the story position is", ""+pos1);
    FragmentManager fm= getSupportFragmentManager();
    ReadFragment f2=(ReadFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.pager);
    f2.setStory(position, pos1);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
}

@Override
public void send(int pos) {
    Log.e("You got here",""+pos);
    FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
    StoryFragment f2=(StoryFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.pager);
    if(f2!=null){
        position=pos;
        f2.getPos(pos);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }
}
```

}

This is MyFirstFragment

```
package com.davemcelf.fiction;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * 
 */
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
communicator comm;
public CategoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;

}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    final String[] cate={"Romance","Joke","Horror","Poem"};
    comm=(communicator)getActivity();
    ListView cat=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.category);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.text_list_view, cate);
    cat.setAdapter(adapter);
    cat.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("hahaha",""+pos);
    comm.send(pos);
}
  @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            comm =(communicator) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

}
```

This is my SecondFragment

```
package com.davemcelf.fiction;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * 
 */
public class StoryFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
ListView list;
sendtocontext comm;

public StoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
comm=(sendtocontext) getActivity();
list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.story);
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_story, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
public void getPos(int pos){
    final String[] romance={"The Stranger","Just My Sight Into","Love Story"};
    final String[] joke={"Bean","drop"};
    final String[] horror={"The Movie","Skinless"};
    Log.e("Gomananana", "this position is"+pos);
    switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.text_list_view, romance);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                break;
            case 1:
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.text_list_view, joke);
                list.setAdapter(adapter1);
                break;
            case 2:
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.text_list_view, horror);
                list.setAdapter(adapter2);
                break;
            }
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    comm.sendcontext(pos);
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        comm =(sendtocontext) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}
```

}

> this is where is got error 
>   This is my Third Fragment

```
package com.davemcelf.fiction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
* 
*/
public class ReadFragment extends Fragment {
TextView story;
public ReadFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("read ","Create ");

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_read1, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
public void setStory(int pos,int pos1){
    story=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.context1);
    Log.e("Story here", ""+pos +","+pos1);
    switch(pos){
    case 0:
        switch (pos1) {
        case 0:
            story.setText(R.string.The_Stranger);
            break;
        case 1:
            story.setText(R.string.Just_My_Sight_Into);
            break;
        default:
            story.setText(R.string.Love_Story);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        switch (pos1) {
        case 0:
            story.setText(R.string.The_Haunted);
            break;

        default:
            story.setText(R.string.Skinless);
            break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

LogCat:

```
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936): java.lang.ClassCastException:      com.davemcelf.fiction.CategoryFragment cannot be cast to com.davemcelf.fiction.ReadFragment
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at com.davemcelf.fiction.MainActivity.sendcontext(MainActivity.java:51)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at com.davemcelf.fiction.StoryFragment.onItemClick(StoryFragment.java:64)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at    android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at     android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1490)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3275)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4518)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native  Method)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-17 22:11:58.524: E/AndroidRuntime(25936):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I got the Error when i move from the third fragment to the others 2 fragment. what wrong?

Comment: Please state what you are trying to accomplish with the code. It will help people look at specific parts of code and give you the answer much faster.

Comment: ReadFragment f2=(ReadFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.pager); this is your error, every fragment must have unique id, by which you can find this fragment in Fragment manager. But you use same id for every fragments. So you get from fragment manager same fragment every time.

Comment: @VyprNoch i want the user to choose the category and the story from fragment 1 and 2.. and then, show the story in the third fragment..

Comment: @Govtart but i use viewPager in the xml.... so, do i have to add the three fragments to the MainActivity.xml?

Comment: Just follow this official guild: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html You do not clear understand how fragment mechanism works...